# ¿Como hacer que javascript abra una URL solo luego de detectar que salió de la URL principal?

Tags: javascript, script, redirección

vengo acá a pedir ayuda. estoy haciendo un script de greasemonkey que haga lo siguiente:
Revise si uno de los sitios incluye en el URL la palabra "ABC", de ser así extraiga el ID incluído en esta URL, para posteriormente partiendo de este ID generar un elace nuevo.

Hasta acá todo bien, hice el script y lo que describo acá lo hace perfectamente, dejo abajo el ejemplo del enlace y el script que hice.

> https://mainsite.com/ABC.aspx?123=XXX&TEST=321&SSID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

```js
if(window.location.href.indexOf("ABC") > -1) {
      const url = document.URL
      const id = url.split('=').pop();
      var newURL  =  "https://newsite.com/" + id
      window.location.replace (newURL);
}
```

Ahora el problema es que ese link mainsite.com por si solo redirecciona a otra página (el host al que redirecciona varía, no siempre es el mismo), lo que quiero es que el enlace generado se abra una vez mansite.com redireccione, porque mi script abrirá inmediatamente newsite.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
La ayuda que necesito es para que me den una idea para hacer que el enlace solo se abra al salir de mainsite.com.

No sé si me expliqué bien, lo que necesito es que en lugar de abrir el nuevo enlace de inmediato lo haga a penas el navegador salga de mainsite.com

Otra idea:
Revisé la página y mientras está cargando aparece esto:

```js
<img alt="Loading" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -24px; margin-left: -24px" src="aprt/images/loader-green.gif" width="48" height="48">
```

¿Podría abrirse la página al detectar que desaparece eso?

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Probé esto y no funcionó, intentando que cuando desapareciera la imagen de "Loading" abriera la página.

```js
if(window.location.href.indexOf("ABC") > -1) {
      const url = document.URL
      const id = url.split('=').pop();
      var newURL  =  "https://newsite.com/" + id
}
if(document.getElementById('Loading').innerHTML)==-1)
{
  window.location.replace (newURL);
}
```

Comment: O sea, quieres un popup... no se si esta pregunta es éticamente correcta para que te demos una solución. No dudo de tus motivos pero imagínate que te la damos y luego funciona bien y los bloqueadores de popups no consiguen pararlo... y luego viene un saboteador de internet y lo usa con propósitos deshonestos haciendo que el usuario se vuelva loco cerrando ventanas o pestañas mientras el otro va haciendo caja... no se yo...

Comment: No es algo como un popup porque el script carga la página en la misma ventana, solo ve el código, quiero que:
var newURL  =  "https://newsite.com/"
cargue solo luego que la página haya cargado bien y ya, no creo que la solución que me puedan dar pueda usarse con motivos de hacer spam o algo similar.

Comment: Quizás la manera más fácil de lograrlo es que javascript chequee la imagen loader-green.gif y una vez haya desaparecido del body proceda a abrir la página, lo que no sé es como expresar esto que te digo en javascript, si está en tu conocimiento y me explicas te estaría agradecido.